# Is there an index that compares the percentage of each President's executive orders that were challenged in court?

Tags: united-states, executive-order

It appears that President Trump's executive orders were often being challenged in court, such as his order to end the DACA program or his decision to ban nationals of certain countries from entering the US. Is this a typical occurrence for Presidents, or was Trump an exception? Is there a way to measure this?

Comment: A more relevant index that "challenged in court" would be "reversed by a court decision". Of course that means that to get the numbers you would have to wait several years until the different lawsuits are settled.

Comment: @SJuan76 the index could just measure "temporarily blocked by the court" too

Comment: It probably *is* an outlier, but what does it tell you? That less effort was put into making the executive order legal?

Comment: @pjc50 it could also tell me if Presidential power is being more and more undermined by judicial challenges.

Comment: How do we distinguish between "checks and balances" and "undermined"? Are the executive orders defined in the Constitution?

Comment: @pjc50 no idea, but whether or not a certain executive order is blocked in court is definitely an objectively measurable metrci

Comment: One could measure it. But so far as I know, no such index currently exists.

Comment: Being blocked could just mean that the court wanted to take more time to look at it and it doesn't reflect on the order itself. There is also the issue with orders that get blocked/reversed not because the order itself had issues but the process that was done to do it did and it just had to be done differently to survive the challenge.